# How do you break out of nested loops in C++?

Tags: c++, break

I am a beginner in C++, and I am wondering how to break out of nested loops. Is there a `break(2)`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
            for (int b = 7; b < 12; b++) {
                // Some statements
                // Is break(2) right or wrong
                // or can I use 'break; break;'?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `goto`.

Comment: No, `break(2)` doesn't exist; `goto` is the option

Comment: So much nested code is a reason to refactor

Comment: Can you use goto in the in the for or not?

Comment: This is about the only place a `goto` is acceptable. A function is preferred (imho). A `goto` is actually better than `break(2)` would be if it were legal.

Comment: do you have to include anything?

Comment: I'm tempted to reverse-dupe-close the other question, as this one looks far better.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `goto`. It's essentially the same function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(int x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
        for(int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
            for(int b = 7; b < 12; b++) {
                if (condition)
                    goto endOfLoop;
            }
        }
    }

    endOfLoop:
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Can you use goto in the in the for or not?

Comment: @Ian you can use it everywhere. Don't reach for it first thing, though.

Comment: @Ian: you can safely `goto` *out* of the loop, but beware `goto` *into* the loop.

Comment: thanks I get it now. :)

Comment: Just keep in mind that a goto kills all optimizations by waiting for the CPU's cycles to flush what's still in its pipe by forcing the compiler to add nop ASM opcodes before the goto. In short: it is a performance killer.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no `break(2)` unfortunately (or perhaps fortunately, depending on your views of deep nesting of scopes).

There are two main ways to solve this:

1. Set a flag before you `break` which tells the outer loop to stop.
2. Put some of your nested loops into functions, so that they can do `break` but also `return` to jump out.  For example:

---

```
// returns true if should be called again, false if not
bool foo() {
    for(int j = 6; j < 9; j++) {
        for(int b = 7; b < 12; b++) {
            if (something) {
                break; // one level
            }
            if (whatever) {
                return true; // two levels
            }
            if (another) {
                return false; // three levels
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    for(int x = 5; x < 10; x++) {
        if (!foo()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Abusing functions or stuffing additional flags inside iteration logic to perform flow control are two good ways to make a mess of your code.

Comment: As opposed to `goto` or even exceptions?

Comment: @Quentin: The approaches I have outlined are very common in C and C++ and would be recognized by most anyone as normal practice.  What, in your opinion, is the better approach?

Comment: @LogicStuff, exceptions as a flow of control mechanism!? Better not.

Comment: @LogicStuff as opposed to `goto`, which is the last flow control primitive when the other ones (here `break`) aren't enough. Exceptions should not in any way be involved in flow control.

Comment: (I listed two, maybe only one scorned alternatives, It was not a suggestion)

Comment: @JohnZwinck Dillydill123's answer is pretty much the canonical structure of a nested loop break.